# How to customize command not found style in zsh

Tags: macos, shell, zsh, customization, zshrc

How to customize `command not found` in zsh (MacOS)

For example:

```
MacBook-Pro: ~ justin$ lll
zsh: command not found: lll
```

To

```
MacBook-Pro: ~ justin$ lll
zsh: WTFFFFF command not found: lll
```

There is a [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42865537/customize-command-not-found-message-in-bash) discuss about the case in bash, but i can't find anything like `command-not-found` in `~/zshrc`, `/private/etc/zshrc`, and `/private/etc/zprofile`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

zsh looking for the function `command_not_found_handler` in the zshrc file (instead of `command_not_found_handle` of bash).

Add to your ~/.zshrc file something like:

```
command_not_found_handler() {
    echo "zsh: WTFFFFF command not found: $@"
    return 127
}
```

or customize it further. Notice the `return 127` line: the default command not found handler function returns the exit code 127 so this way you can keep this behavior. You can test the exit code with `echo $?`.

Comment: I also found [this](https://github.com/Tireg/zsh-macos-command-not-found/blob/master/macos-command-not-found.plugin.zsh) project that you can use